# Machine Learning brain.js probability

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, brain.js

We conduct customer surveys on a weekly basis about our products and
We ask for 5 products he choose 2 favorites.

I would like to know how do brain.js learn about the choices and give me a probability for the next research based on the previous ones.

Study Links:
https://towardsdatascience.com/probability-fundamentals-of-machine-learning-part-1-a156b4703e69
https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-probability-statistics-f830f8c09326

**Json**

```
{
    "products" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Product 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Product 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Product 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Product 4"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Product 5"
        }
    ],

    "data" : [
        {
            "choice": [1, 2]
        },
        {
            "choice": [1, 5]
        },
        {
            "choice": [3, 5]
        },
        {
            "choice": [1, 4]
        },
        {
            "choice": [4, 5]
        },
        {
            "choice": [1, 2]
        },
        {
            "choice": [1, 3]
        },
        {
            "choice": [2, 5]
        }
    ]
}
```

**I would like brain.js to show me which products are most likely to be chosen in survey 9? **

Comment: idk why nobody even commented or anything to this question.. but, ur saying it supposed to take those 2 favourite choices and *GUESS* a third?